# PHP SELECT query With condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, U.full_name, U.profile_pic, U.username, U.uid FROM t_haps_wall M, t_users U, t_join_user F WHERE
        M.uid_fk=U.uid AND F.uid=U.uid AND M.uid_fk = F.uid AND F.status='joining' order by M.msg_id desc ") or die(mysql_error());
```

That's my SELECT code to show some message and now I want to add 1 condition :

```
AND M.uid_fk='$uid'
```

So where I can put that in my complete code.
I already tried but no effects. Or something missing / wrong code? 

Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should put it in the `WHERE` clause, and use the ANSI SQL-92 instead like so:

```
SELECT 
  M.msg_id, 
  M.uid_fk, 
  M.message, 
  M.created,
  U.full_name, 
  U.profile_pic, 
  U.username, 
  U.uid 
FROM t_haps_wall       M
INNER JOIN t_users     U ON  M.uid_fk = U.uid
INNER JOIN t_join_user F ON  F.uid    = U.uid
WHERE F.status = 'joining' 
  AND M.uid_fk ='$uid' -- your condition here 
order by M.msg_id desc
```

**Note that:** Your code this way is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) , use PDO or prepared statements instead. See this for more details:

- [**Best way to prevent SQL injection in PHP?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: You might want to write something about SQL injections

Comment: @Nagini - How it has no effect? any errors? doesn't return any data? Try to remove the condition `AND M.uid_fk ='$uid'` and check your data, may be doesn't contain that Id.

Comment: @Nagini Also, try to run and debug the query in [an SQL client](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list) before using it in your application code

Answer (score 0):

Like this?..

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, U.full_name, U.profile_pic, U.username, U.uid FROM t_haps_wall M, t_users U, t_join_user F WHERE
    M.uid_fk=U.uid AND F.uid=U.uid AND M.uid_fk = F.uid AND F.status='joining' AND M.uid_fk=".$uid." order by M.msg_id desc ") or die(mysql_error());
```

I was assuming you wanted to place the `M.uid_fk=".$uid."` in your `WHERE` condition. The (.) operator isn't really necessary because you have double quotes around your query, but I like to use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you have searched first before raising this question ::

Anyways ::
check the placement of NEW_COLUMN

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, U.full_name, U.profile_pic, U.username, U.uid, NEW_COLUMN FROM t_haps_wall M, t_users U, t_join_user F WHERE
        M.uid_fk=U.uid AND F.uid=U.uid AND M.uid_fk = F.uid AND F.status='joining' order by M.msg_id desc ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it *wherever** you want after the `WHERE` clause. Try with this updated query

```
$sql =
"
SELECT 
   M.msg_id, 
   M.uid_fk, 
   M.message, 
   M.created, 
   U.full_name, 
   U.profile_pic, 
   U.username, 
   U.uid 
FROM 
   t_haps_wall M, 
   t_users U, 
   t_join_user F 
WHERE 
   M.uid_fk=U.uid 
   AND F.uid=U.uid 
   AND M.uid_fk = F.uid 
   AND F.status='joining' 
   AND M.uid_fk='".$uid."'
ORDER BY 
   M.msg_id DESC
";

$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

*I have added it at the end. Although, I say wherever and it works; it is not strictly the most optimal way. Placement of conditions can often influence how efficiently the queries run